# Selenium WebDriver - cannot locate some elements inside iFrame

Tags: python

I'm running test scripts on the Shopify checkout page, and while I am able to switch to the iFrame and get the Card Number element, the same approach doesn't seem to work for the other input elements (id='expiry', id='name' etc)

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUr70.png)
[Inspect iFrame screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaYXw.jpg)

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe']")))
    element12 = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'number')))
    element12.click()
    element12.send_keys('1111222233334444')
```

Have also tried driver.switchTo().defaultContent() and switching back to iFrame again, but same error

```
    element13 = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'expiry')))
    element13.click()
    element13.send_keys('1220')
```

Here's the error I get for element13.

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (489, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue - the elements were in separate iFrames. Modified my code to retrieve the iFrames using xpath and a partial match on the different id fields